# Pandas resample at a custom start timestamp

Tags: pandas

I’m trying to resample data at a given start time

```
my program:
sales = [{'Timestamp': '2018-06-22 15:15:00', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140},
        {'Timestamp': '2018-06-22 15:44:00',  'Jan': 250, 'Feb': 250, 'Mar': 250},
        {'Timestamp': '2018-06-22 15:46:00',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
        {'Timestamp': '2018-06-22 16:16:00',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
        {'Timestamp': '2018-06-22 16:18:00',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
        {'Timestamp': '2018-06-22 16:20:00',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

ResampledDF = pd.DataFrame()
ResampledDF['J'] = df.Jan.resample("30T").max()
ResampledDF['F'] = df.Feb.resample("30T").max()
ResampledDF['M'] = df.Mar.resample("30T").max()
print(ResampledDF)
```

Output:

```
                       J    F    M
Timestamp                         
2018-06-22 15:00:00  150  200  140
2018-06-22 15:30:00  250  250  250
2018-06-22 16:00:00  200  210  215
```

Here output has automatically sampled data starting at 15:00:00, whereas i want the first row at 15:15:00 and second at 15:45:00 etc. like below

Required Output:

```
                        J    F    M
 Timestamp                         
 2018-06-22 15:15:00  250  250  250
 2018-06-22 15:45:00  200  210  215
 2018-06-22 16:15:00  200  210  215
```

Answer (score 4):

use [`base` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
In [233]: df.resample('30T', base=15).max()
Out[233]:
                     Feb  Jan  Mar
Timestamp
2018-06-22 15:15:00  250  250  250
2018-06-22 15:45:00  210  200  215
2018-06-22 16:15:00  210  200  215
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU, somehow missed to check this option